How to run vis_cam.py in the project of openmixup?
Q:qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/root/anaconda/envs/openmix/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found. This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
def show_cam_grad(grayscale_cam, src_img, title, out_path=None):
    """fuse src_img and grayscale_cam and show or save."""
    grayscale_cam = grayscale_cam[0, :]
    src_img = np.float32(src_img) / 255
    visualization_img = show_cam_on_image(
        src_img, grayscale_cam, use_rgb=False)

    if out_path:
        mmcv.imwrite(visualization_img, str(out_path))
    else:
        mmcv.imshow(visualization_img, win_name=title)

I have installed "opencv-python-headless", but it remind me that I need to execute "pip install opencv-contrib-python". After installing, the question Q comes up again.

[mre] required.

Does this answer your question? "qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found."

Also check this answer.
